# Laravel Homestead permission denied to .bash_aliases

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I just setup a vagrant box using `laravel/homestead` on Mac OS 10.9. I get the following error after I connect via SSH:

```
-bash: /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases: Permission denied
```

Haven't seen this when I provisioned on my Windows setup. What could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I just did the following, though I can't figure why this was necessary to begin with:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.bash_aliases
```